# error in visualization internal server error kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, kibana-7

I setup an Elasticsearch Kibana stack with xpack.
from the built-in user, i logged in to the account and created a `kibana_user` and a `kibana_dashboard_only` user.

When i logged in, the login was successful in both the users but when i go to the dashboards or discover,
Im getting an

`error in visualization internal server error` 
pop up error.

Why is this and how can i fix this?
All actions work fine with the built-in `elastic` user account.
Please help me.

Comment: You also need to give that user [read access](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/xpack-dashboard-only-mode.html) to the `.kibana` index

Comment: you are right! thanks very much! @Val

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need to give that user [read access](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/xpack-dashboard-only-mode.html) to the `.kibana` index

Comment: Yes, @val, I was able to create a new role and provide the index access to the users. The default settings for available roles cannot be changed. Thanks very much!